# Is there a method to return the list of a certain type within inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a superclass, Registration, which owns two other subclasses, Student and Professional. Within another class, I have a list that manages the registrations.

I have to foresee this method:

```java
public ArrayList<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x)
```

If x is 0, the method must return all students, while if x is 1, it must return all professionals. Could you tell me how it's done?

Comment: Before you proceed I will suggest you to look for SOLID principles in Object Oriented Programming

Comment: I would suggest looking up the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Since you need to have Sudent's and Professional's separated, I'd have two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to filter these values like this:

```java
public List<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return registrations.stream()
            .filter(r -> r instanceof Student)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (x == 1) {
        return registrations.stream()
            .filter(r -> r instanceof Professional)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    return Collections.emptyList(); //default if x not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to create another class which takes registrationList in constructor and has a method to filter registration based on type in input. This way you can put filtering functionality outside of class having Registration list(S principle in SOLID)

```
public class FilteredRegistrationByType {

List<Registration> regList = new ArrayList<Registration>();
public FilteredRegistrationByType(List<Registrations> regList)
{
    this.regList = regList;
}
public List<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return this.regList.stream()
            .filter(r -> r instanceof Student)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (x == 1) {
        return this.regList.stream()
            .filter(r -> r instanceof Professional)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    return Collections.emptyList(); //default if x not valid
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One implement getRegistrationsByTypes in super class, two implement it in a Student and Professional class.

**Option one:**

```java
    // Add this one to super calass and, Implement it in the sub classes
    public abstract ArrayList<Registrations> getRegisteration();
    
    public ArrayList<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x){
        if (this instanceof Student && x == 0){
            return getRegisteration(); // It will returns all students
        } else if (this instanceof Professional && x == 1){
            return getRegisteration(); // It will returns all professionals
        }
        return null; // If it isn't student/professional or x > 1, x <0
    }
```

**Option two:**

```java
    // Declare the following method in super class
    public abstract ArrayList<Registrations> getRegisteration(in x);
    

    // implement it in subclasses

    class Student{
    ...
    public ArrayList<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x){
        if (x == 0){
            return registrationList;
        }
    }

    class Professional{
    ...
    public ArrayList<Registrations> getRegistrationsByTypes(int x){
        if (x == 1){
            return registrationList;
        }
    }
```

Polymorphism makes option two better and cleaner.